# QGIS "disable" database [PostGIS] connections

Tags: qgis, postgis, configuration

Is it possible to "disable" a PostGIS connection within QGIS?

I am in an environment with several test-databases on different testing VMs which are not necessarily booted up all the time.

QGIS tries to connect to all the databases on startup. For every offline database that results in a error-message-window popping up.

I want to avoid deleting the connections in order to mitigate that problem.